# How To Center Icon in Android Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to center the icon in the android action bar.  I'm using a custom layout that has a button on the left side, an icon in the center and the menu options on the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/slideMenuButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_bookmark" />

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"  >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried this with and without the RelativeLayout wrapping the ImageView.  The left button shows up fine, and I can set the icon with layout_toRightOf, but I can't get it to center.  Anyone have any ideas?

Edit:
Here's the android code in the on create method.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

Comment: Are you able to find any difference when you remove android:orientation = "vertical" from your parent relativelayout? I suggest you not to wrap imageview again in the relativelayout(second one) and check.

Comment: Just tried with no relative layout around the image view, and with the android:orientation removed from the main layout.  The image just ends up sitting on top of the button.  The button is exactly where I want it, I just need to center that image in the action bar.

Comment: See my answer. Let me know if you still don't get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay. This should work. Try this(**Tested in normal activity**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/slideMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is putting the imageview on top of the button.  When you tested this in a normal activity was it the action bar of that activity?

Comment: This actually works, but only if you don't inflate a menu in OnCreateOptionsMenu.  So if you want right hand buttons, they have to be explicitly added.

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers doesn't work for me (on Android 4.4 devices), because the outer container view groups did not expand to the full with, so the container group and the centered inner logo was already left aligned in the title bar.

I found a layout that works with the regular action bar menu (on right side) and regardless of enabling the regular action bar logo and title (on left side). This example only centers an additional logo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <View android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/my_logo"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:contentDescription="Logo"
        />

    <View android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

You have to enable the custom view by this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

but not this method (it disables all other elements in action bar).

```
// actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Comment: This looks like a hack to me. Any better solutions?

Comment: That's clever, I like it

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom view to the action bar. Just add a LinearLayout as the custom view and add sub views to the linearlayout. I used this technique to add 4 buttons right in the middle.

To add a custom view use actionBar.setCustomView(view). Also set the option DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM using actionBar.setDisplayOptions.

Once you have a custom view in the bar then use normal layout procedures to get the effect you  want. One trick you could use would be to have 3 nested linear layouts and assign each a weight. For example 1,4,1 so the center layout gets the most space. Here is an example, of course you can leave out the buttons on the right side layout if you want it to be blank. With this approach you can achieve the exact center.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#0F0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00F"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm using a custom view already.  The layout in the question is the layout for the custom view.  I've edited to show the android code.

Comment: This layout has the button and the image view directly next to each other.  I'm wondering if the fact that it's an action bar is the problem.

Comment: Did you try this layout in the eclipse layout editor? I generated this from scratch, not using your stuff. You will need to replace the Buttons I put in the layout with whatever other views you need.

Comment: I modified it to use my buttons/images.  The imageview sits directly next to the image button.  Not in the center of the action bar. I'm wondering if there's some weirdness with how the action bar manages its view due to the fact that it's adding menu items on the right.