# Center action bar custom

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have placed a custom view in the action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/internal_header_logo_gasbuddy" />   
</RelativeLayout>

// here is a snip of tha runtime
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setTitle("");

getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custombar, null);
getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

This almost does what I want.
The graphic is centered in the center area of the actionbar between the NavDrawerIcon, Programicom, title, customview, settingsicon

I want the new view centered in the width of the whole display, as such it would not move as other ab elements come and go

help is very much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596090/how-to-center-icon-in-android-action-bar?rq=1