# Start activity without ActionBar and add it in the onCreate event

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the AppCompat/ActionBarCompat library and I need to create a custom ActionBar. I need to open the activity without an ActionBar and enable it only when I add the custom view. How can I do this?

PS: I need to define the activity to not use an ActionBar through the AndroidManifest.xml and my application minimum API level is 10.

Comment: Do you want to disable the Action bar?

Comment: Disable it before Activity load. But enable it after adding a custom view like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596090/how-to-center-icon-in-android-action-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.hide() the action bar and then .show() the action bar when your ready for it

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

...

```
private ActionBar mActionbar;
```

...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionbar.hide()
}
```

...
somewhere when something cool happens

```
mActionbar.show();
```